# is it haram going to the pub

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

my friends are going to see the euros final at the pub and I really want to watch it with them but not sure if going to the pub is haram. I will not consume any food or drink if I go.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is haram. It was narrated that ‘Umar ibn al-Khattaab (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever believes in Allaah and the Last Day, let him not sit at a table where wine is being drunk.”

Narrated by Ahmad, 126; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Irwa’ al-Ghaleel, 7/6.